# AM-protocol when Merlin does not know the input

Tags: interactive-proofs, pseudorandomness

In classical interactive protocols  we assume that Merlin knows Arthur's input $x$.

However we can consider a model where it is not a case. I think that this model is more powerful than classical.

The idea of using  Merlin's unknowing of $x$ is the following.

Arthur can ask about several inputs $x_1,\cdots, x_k$, such that one of them is equal to $x$.

Assume that Arthur knows the answers for all $x_i$ except $x$. Assume also that Merlin can not distinguish $x$ from other inputs. Then Merlin has to give right answers for all $x_i$ including $x$.

Let us give an example. Consider the problem of distinguishing random strings from pseudorandom strings  that are outputs of a polynomial-time computable generator $G_n: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^{2n}$. We assume that there is the following distribution on the inputs: one half of the inputs are honest random and other half is pseudorandom (distributing uniformly as outputs of $G_n$). So we are interesting in average-case complexity of this problem.

I argue that this problem belongs to AM-[where Merlin do not knows the input] (even though I didn't define this class :)).

Indeed, denote Arthur's input as $x$.
He can samples, say, $100$ random strings and $100$ pseudorandom stings. Then Arthur chooses a random permutation for his $201$ strings and ask Merlin to distinguish all of them.

If Merlin gives $200$ correct answers then Arthur can assume that Merlin's answer about $x$ is also correct   - the probability of the incorrectness is less than $1$ percent.

To all of my knowledge we do not know a similar result for classical AM-protocol, so we can conjecture that AM-[where Merlin do not knows the input] is more powerful than classical AM.

Unfortunately, there exists a problem with defining this language formally - it seems that we can not amplificate error as in standard random classes...

So, my question is the following:

Has anything like this been considered before?